# Windows 8 Store App Convert Trial to buy

Tags: windows, windows-8

I have an app that expires after 30 days. After that you will get a expire message and to buy. The code I have to buy is:

```
LicenseInformation licenseInformation = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;
         if (licenseInformation.IsTrial)
    {

        try 
        {
            await CurrentApp.RequestAppPurchaseAsync(false);
```

For some reason sometimes nothing happens and sometimes I get a message the app is no longer available.

Anyone know why it's not asking them to buy?

Comment: Is this app actually in the Store right now?  If not then you'll have to use the CurrentAppSimulator class to test this code.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator.aspx

Comment: Yes the app is in the store for over a month. Its called yivosoft memory match.